# SQL Trigger not executing when its intended

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

Parts (**pid**, pname, color)
Suppliers (**sid**, sname , address)
Catalog (**sid, pid**, price)

SQL Trigger - No supplier may supply green and red parts

What i have so far

```
CREATE TRIGGER NoRedAndGreenParts
BEFORE INSERT ON Parts
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Parts P1 WHERE N.pid = P1.pid AND P1.color = 'red' AND EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Catalog C1, Parts P2 WHERE C1.sid = N.sid AND C1.pid = P2.pid AND P2.color = 'green' ) 
INTERSECT
( SELECT * FROM Parts P3 WHERE N.pid = P3.pid AND P3.color = 'green' AND EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Catalog C2, Parts P4 WHERE C2.sid = N.sid AND C2.pid = P4.pid AND P4.color = 'red' ) 
);
```

Tried the following trigger but it doesn't work when its intended to. What exactly is the problem?

EDIT:
I am trying to prevent an insertion into the table if a supplier suddenly decides to supply green parts when they are already supplying red parts

i.e. Supplier can only supply either red or green parts but not both

Comment: A syntax error is one problem. The trigger code is not complete. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to prevent an insertion into the table if a supplier suddenly decides to supply green parts when they are already supplying red parts

i.e. Supplier can only supply either red or green parts but not both

Comment: I'm surprised you can create this trigger on SQL Server, you sure it's not MySQL